# Get tables which has been altered w.r.t. columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get Table names whose schema has been altered, but by alter I mean only when a column has been modified or added. The modify_date in sys.objects where type="U" gives me those tables too whose index or views have been altered.

Therefore I need a script which will give me only those tables, where there was column modification or column addition only.

Below it the script which is in generic

```
select s.name+'.'+o.name
from sys.objects o
JOIN sys.schemas s
ON o.schema_id=s.schema_id
where type IN ('U')
and modify_date > '20160404'
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Get me table names which have been altered from a given date. By alter I mean either table column was modified or a new column was added on to the table.